# Can satisfying two properties satisfied by an equivalence relation automatically imply that the third property is satisfied?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$R$ is said to be a relation over a set, $S$, if $R\subseteq S\times S$, where $S\times S$ is defined as the Cartesian product, such that $S\times S=\{(x,y):x\in S,\,y\in S\}$. A relation is said to be an equivalence relation if it satisfies the following three properties:

1. $(x,x)\in R$
2. $(x,y)\in R\Rightarrow (y,x)\in R$
3. $(x,y)\in R\land (y,z)\in R\Rightarrow (x,z)\in R$

That is, $R$ is an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. So $(x,y)\in R$, for $x=y$ is an equivalence relation while, $(x,y)\in R$, for $|x-y|\leq 4$ is not (as it is not transitive). My question is then:

> Do any two of these properties imply the third? That is, if a relation, $R$ exhibits both reflexivity and symmetry, must it be transitive? Or similarly, if $R$ is reflexive and transitive, can we automatically say that is symmetric? Does some such theorem exist, or must we verify all three properties for each $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No two of these imply the third. The following are counterexamples to each possible implication.

(i) Let X = $\{x,y,z \}$. Then $R = \{ (x,y),(y,z), (y,x), (z,y), (x,x), (y,y),(z,z) \}$ is symmetric and reflexive but not transitive since $(x,z) \not \in R$.

(ii) The empty relation (that is $R = \emptyset$) is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive.

(iii) The relation $R = \{(x,x),(y,y),(z,z), (x,y)\}$ on $X$ as in (i) is reflexive and transitive but is not symmetric since $(y,x) \not \in R$